# Socket connection to serial port

Tags: php, sockets, backup

I needed connect by serial port to APC backup and get any value from it.

How can I connect with PHP to serial port?

I'm using S.O Ubuntu 13.04, and this testing is in my pc directly connect to APC.

Comment: I think you can use Direct IO extension for this, fetch more information from here : http://www.brainboxes.com/faq/items/how-do-i-control-a-serial-port-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Try with these two links ,are awesome:

```
http://wirespeed.xs4all.nl/mediawiki/index.php/Udev_rules_file_for_Arduino_boards
http://wirespeed.xs4all.nl/mediawiki/index.php/Cat_ttyUSB0
```

Answer (score 0):

Test you with this:

```
<?php
/**
 *
*/

/  Set up serial open - 
$fp =fopen("/dev/ttyUSB", "w");

//check the GET actions variable to see if something needs to be done
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    //Action has been requested

    //Issue the command we wish to send to the Arduino
    if ($_GET['action'] == "true") {
        //UP LED true - for this simple script we are just looking for either a 1 or 0 
        fwrite($fp, chr(1));

    } else if ($_GET['action'] == "false") {
        //Down LED off
        fwrite($fp, chr(0));

    }

    //We're done, so close the serial port again
    fclose($fp);

}


?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Arduino LED control</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>LED Control system - Arduino Interface</h1>
<p><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=true" ?>">
Turn LED On.</a></p>
<p><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?action=dalse" ?>">
Turn LED Off.</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need serial port and not by USB.